# Правило употребления предлогов "в" и "на"

Tags: предлоги

Объясните мне, пожалуйста, правило употребления предлогов "в" и "на" в русском языке (предложный падеж).

В моей практике часто приходится обучать иностранцев русскому разговорному языку (я не учитель русского языка, я просто помогаю им научиться говорить по-русски). Вот например, у меня сейчас есть несколько ребят, они из Австрии, в русском языке полные нули, т.е. приходится с самых азов обучать (падежи даже брать пока не хочется). Как они мне говорили, в немецком (может быть, я и ошибаюсь, если что, извините, я немецкий не знаю) нет разницы, как ты скажешь "НА совещании" или "В совещании". Они меня спросили, в чем разница между ними. Я, честно говоря, даже никогда и не задумывался на этот счет. Помогите, пожалуйста, в решении данного вопроса.

Comment: А на каком языке вы, простите, общаетесь? )))

Answer (score 3):

Это из Розенталя
**1.** Синонимичны в ряде конструкций предлоги **в – на** и их антонимы **из – с**. Например: *работать в огороде – работать на огороде, ехать в поезде – ехать на поезде, слёзы в глазах – слёзы на глазах.* Между вариантными конструкциями обычно имеются смысловые или стилистические различия.
**2.** Употребление предлога **в** в пространственном значении связано с представлением об ограниченном пространстве, при отсутствии этого значения употребляется предлог **на**. Ср.: *машины стояли во дворе* (окруженное забором или домами пространство) – *дети играли на дворе* (вне дома; ср.: *на дворе сегодня холодно*).
**3.** С административно-географическими наименованиями употребляется предлог **в**, например: *в городе, в районе, в области, в республике; в Сибири, в Белоруссии, в Закавказье*. Сочетание *на Украине* возникло под влиянием украинского языка (ср.: *на Полтавщине, на Черниговщине*) и поддерживается выражением *на окраине*.
**4.** С названиями горных областей употребляется предлог **на**, ср.: *на Алтае, на Кавказе, на Урале* (имеется ввиду горная местность без точно очерченных границ). Но: *в Крыму* (только частично ограниченное горами степное пространство). Употребление предлогов **в – на** при названиях гор во множественном числе придает сочетаниям разное значение: *в Альпах, в Андах, в Апеннинах, в Пиренеях* и т. д. означает «в горах, среди гор»; *на Балканах – на Балканском полуострове, на Карпатах – на поверхности гор*.
**5.** В некоторых случаях отражается влияние народного языка,  профессионального употребления и т. д. Ср.: *работает в фотостудии – фильм дублирован на киностудии* (профессиональный оборот, под влиянием сочетания *на кинофабрике*; ср.: *работает на радио, на телевидении*); *Я побежал в кухню…* (Горький). *– Нянька приходила на кухню…* (Короленко) (второй вариант под влиянием народной речи).
**6.** Иногда сказывается исторически сложившаяся традиция; ср.: *в деревне – на хуторе, в селе – первый на селе работник; в учреждении – на предприятии, в переулке – на улице*; ср. также: *в комбинате бытового обслуживания – на мясокомбинате*.
**7.** На выбор предлога влияет семантика управляющего слова и значение всего сочетания. Ср.: *поехал на вокзал – вошёл в вокзал, пошёл на мельницу – вошёл в мельницу* (сказывается соответствие приставки **в-** и предлога **в**).
**8.** В выражениях *на почте, на заводе, на фабрике* употребление предлога **на** объясняется тем, что первоначально понятия «почта», «завод», «фабрика» не связывались с представлением о закрытом помещении или здании: почта когда-то была на почтовой станции, на которой содержали ямщиков и держали лошадей; завод или фабрика могли занимать открытую территорию и состоять из нескольких сооружений (ср.: *в мастерской, в цехе* – с представлением о закрытом помещении). Употребляются сочетания: *на избирательном участке* (ср.: *в полицейском участке*), *на полевом стане* (ср.: *в военном стане*), *в агитпункте* (ср.: *на наблюдательном пункте*).
**9.** При названиях зрелищных организаций и мероприятий установилось такое употребление: *в театре, в кино, в цирке* (имеется в виду помещение), *на концерте, на опере, на спектакле* (имеется в виду исполнение, представление). В профессиональном употреблении встречаются сочетания: *работает на театре, занят в концерте* (ср.: *служит на флоте*).
**10.** При названиях учебных заведений употребляется предлог **в**: *в университете, в институте, в техникуме, в школе*; при названиях частей учебного заведения – предлог **на**: *на филологическом факультете, на романском отделении, на втором курсе*. Сочетания *в классе, в аудитории* связаны с обычным использованием предлога **в** при обозначении закрытого помещения.
**11.** При названиях средств передвижения обычно употребляется предлог **на**, ср.: *на пароходе, на катере, на поезде, на трамвае, на автобусе, на метро, на самолёте* и т. д. Употребление предлога **в** предполагает нахождение внутри предмета: *спал в автомобиле, сидел в машине, обедал в самолёте, рыба валялась в лодке* и т. д. Ср. предлоги при названиях закрытых и открытых видов экипажей: *в карете, в лимузине – на телеге, на подводе*. Возможные варианты связаны с условиями контекста; ср.: *с трудом удалось сесть в трамвай – сел на трамвай, чтобы скорее добраться до дому*.
**12.** Как указано выше, антонимические пары образуются предлогами **на – с**, **в – из**, например: *поехал на Кавказ – вернулся с Кавказа, поехал в Крым – вернулся из Крыма*.

Comment: «Вошёл в мельницу»... Это зачем же так усложнять? Можно просто «зайти на мельницу». Вообще, копировать словарные статьи смысла нет, достаточно ссылки и напутствия.

Answer (score 2):

"В" = "внутри". Аналог - английское "in".

"На" = "на поверхности". Аналог - английское "on".

Конкретное применение, зачастую, складывалось "исторически". И определить применение "по правилам" вряд-ли удастся.

Comment: Я и хотел бы им объяснить с точки зрения английского языка. Но, к сожалению, они сами в английском не сильны, а в немецком языке нет (опять таки, наверное) различий между "in" и "on"

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, нужно обратить внимание обучающихся на то, что в русском эти существительные употребляются с разными предлогами после разных по смыслу глаголов (здесь "присутствовать на" или "участвовать в" совещании). Примеры таких сочетаний нужно запоминать и усваивать: при изучении иностранного языка конструирование выражений по правилам не всегда возможно и может приводить к сочетаниям, которые никогда не употребляются в изучаемом языке. Например, в китайском суп не "едят", а "пьют", в английском нельзя сказать буквально "объявить о... (announce about...)" - там это переходный глагол, и т. д. В таких случаях бывают полезны словари сочетаемости (русского не попадалось, но напр. для английского есть Oxdord Collocations Dictionary и др.), в которых словарные статьи дают сочетаемость каждого слова с другими частями речи, в частности, с предлогами до и после слова.

Comment: Вот и я уже начинаю думать, что придется им учить некоторые особенности русского языка. Редко что можно объяснить. Вот например с окончаниями, например -ая\-яя, -ое\-ее и тд. Тоже трудно объяснить где -яя, а где -ая...

Comment: Это кака раз просто: краснЫй – краснАя, краснОе, синИй – синЯя, синЕе.

Answer (score 1):

Общее значение предлогов В и НА можно понять из простых примеров: положить в стол (внутрь стола) и положить на стол (на поверхность стола).

Если предмет невещественный, то такую схему можно представить условно: выступить на совещании (представляем совещание в виде площадки), принять участие в совещании (здесь совещание мыслится как совокупность участников, а это уже объемное пространство).

Так можно не просто заучивать предлоги, но и развивать воображение; наверное, так поступают маленькие дети, которые осваивают родной язык без учебников.

А вот еще пример: купить в магазине (в здании) и купить на рынке (на открытом пространстве).  Если рынок становится отвлеченным, ничего не меняется, и мы говорим о ценах на условном рынке.

Answer (score 1):

> Сочетание на Украине возникло под влиянием украинского языка (ср.: на
> Полтавщине, на Черниговщине) и поддерживается выражением на окраине.

Это выражение "на окраине" не есть верным. Украина никогда не была окраиной, кроме как будучи окупированной Московией, а затем - Российской империей. В сегодняшних реалиях Украина – независимое государство в центре Европы. Применение норм языка 19 века "на окраине" или "на Украине" – это имперский пережиток и желание вернуть все вспять, примерно, как писать "ъ", "ить" или "ять".

Comment: Ладно, пусть неверные его кушают.

Comment: Тут скорее нормы языка могут использоваться для передачи неуважения к предмету. Вот например: https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=RU&q=%D0%B2%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5,%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5 — чётко видно что нормой языка является "в Украине", но во время политических потрясений всплывает неуважительная форма — "на Украине".

Answer (score 0):

*Присутствовать **на** совещании*, *участвовать **в** совещании*. Нда, трудновато объяснять... *Участвовать в совещании ~ участвовать в работе совещания*.

Comment: Ещё красивее: "Выбить **на** камне", но "выбить **в** камне".

Comment: Надпись выбивают на камне (на поверхности) или глубоко в камне (в объеме), дорожку вырубают естественно в камне,  увековечить героя также следует в камне, но это уже в виде каменного изваяния. Поэтому всё предсказуемо, всё можно объяснить и  понять.

Comment: *Присутствовать на совещании, участвовать в совещании.* - Это вообще из другой оперы. "Участвовать на" не возможно в принципе. Тут предлог определяется глагольным управлением. И предлог этот имеет другой смысл, к локативу не имеет отношения.