# Приняли участие НА или В заседании комиссии?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно: "На заседании комиссии приняли участие..." или "В заседании комиссии приняли участие..."? Можно ли сказать: "На заседании комиссии приняли участие..."?

Comment: Родственная тема: можно ли всё выводить из общих правил употребления предлогов: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/49590/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0

Answer (score 5):

Участвуют (= принимают участие) всегда **в** чём-то (здесь - в заседании), **на** мероприятии - присутствуют.

Comment: А  в  мероприятии    ( опять  же )   участвуют.

Answer (score 2):

После глагола "участвовать" всегда следует существительное в предложном падеже с предлогом **В** (в чём?): в олимпиаде, в конференции...
Независимо от того, что с другими глаголами при этих существительных всегда используется предлог **НА**: я еду на олимпиаду, я сейчас на олимпиаде, я была на олимпиаде, на конференции и т. п.

Comment: Он участвовал ***при*** переправе через Дунай, переходил Балканы, отсиживался на Шипке, был при последней атаке Плевны; ранили его один раз тяжело, четыре ― легко, и, кроме того, он получил осколком гранаты жестокую контузию в голову. [А. И. Куприн. Гранатовый браслет (1911)]

Comment: ― Я знаю это лучше: я участвовал ***при*** последних минутах покойницы. [Н. В. Гоголь. Мертвые души (1842)] [омонимия не снята] ←

Comment: Клычков только помогал им советом и участвовал ***на*** разных совещаниях, ― время уходило у него на работу с другими дивизионными органами, к которым они с Чапаевым прикоснулись здесь впервые после Белебея. [Д. А. Фурманов. Чапаев (1923)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

Comment: grigoreva-te, нужны примеры как аргументы!

Comment: Правильность этого ответа подтверждают данные по числу вхождений в корпус РЯ следующих сочетаний: «участие в» – 12596, «участвовать в» – 4082, «участие на» – 61, «участвовать на» – 52, «участие при» – 16, «участвова(ть/л/ла/ли) при» – 4+6+0+1 = 11. Эти данные, со всей очевидностью, показывают приоритет предлога «в» перед «на» в сочетании с существительным «участие» и глаголом «участвовать».

Comment: Одна из причин, почему в печать могло проникнуть ненормативное сочетание уже называлась - «корректор не посмел предложить поправку», но есть и другие. В частности, когда объем статьи необходимо было сократить и делалось это в спешке, из вполне приемлемого «фильм даже участвовал (в конкурсном показе) на фестивале в Венеции, но безуспешно», могло получиться «фильм даже участвовал на фестивале в Венеции, но безуспешно».

Answer (score 0):

**Можно ли сказать: "На заседании комиссии приняли участие..."?**

В добротных изданиях такое употребление встречается часто. Например, в биографических справках в различных собраниях сочинений можно встретить такие выражения:

> 14 мая Энгельс участвует на заседании Генерального Совета...
>
> 15 сентября С. Шаумян участвует на заседании ЦК РСДРП...
>
> Октябрь, 15. Ленин участвует на заседании Политбюро ЦК РКП (б)...
>
> А. Ф. Мясникян в Москве участвует на заседании Политбюро Центрального
>   Комитета РКП(б).

Издания второй половины прошлого века. Это издания таких собраний сочинений, в которых в те времена ошибки (да ещё столько!) были маловероятны.

Comment: Здесь вот один учёный предлагает именовать эту распространённую сущность не ошибкой, а "объективной грамматической трудностью": https://thequestion.ru/questions/228369/pochemu-lyudi-chasto-ispolzuyut-predlog-na-vmesto-v-uchastvovat-na-vystavke-konkurse-konferencii-seminare-forume-eto-negramotnost-ili-izmenenie-normy Я не против такой толерантности, но рекомендовать такое употребление, как и автор той статьи, не стал бы. Ваши примеры любопытны, но они все из области партийных канцеляризмов, возможно, корректоры опасались их трогать - не исключаю, что они и в официальных материалах встречались.

Comment: @Alex_ander Согласен с Вами. Примеров вне "партийного канцеляризма" я не встретил. Спасибо за ссылку, интересно. Если Вы добавите её в свой вопрос в качестве аргумента, я тогда удалю свой ответ (удалять его вместе с ценной ссылкой мне жаль :)

Comment: Зачем удалять? Явление интересное, и о его существовании полезно знать.

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от управления глагола. В данном случае корректно: **Участвовать в заседании.** Т.к. глагол "участвовать" требует предлога "в".

Но: присутствовать на заседании. Однако в общем используется оборот "на заседании".

Answer (score 0):

> Как правильно: "На заседании комиссии приняли участие..." или "В
>   заседании комиссии приняли участие..."? Можно ли сказать: "На
>   заседании комиссии приняли участие..."?

Современные правила отдают предпочтение варианту "в заседании" ("в чем?"). 
Но варианты с "на" (и "при") нельзя считать безусловно неправильными, поскольку указанное требование не императивно. К тому же и другие варианты в недавнем прошлом допускались вообще без всякого ограничения, подтверждением чему являются многочисленные примеры не только из партийных изданий, но и из классики.

*Он **участвовал при** переправе через Дунай, переходил Балканы, отсиживался на Шипке, был при последней атаке Плевны; ранили его один раз тяжело, четыре ― легко, и, кроме того, он получил осколком гранаты жестокую контузию в голову. [А. И. Куприн. Гранатовый браслет (1911)]*

*― Я знаю это лучше: я **участвовал при** последних минутах покойницы. [Н. В. Гоголь. Мертвые души (1842)] *

*Клычков только помогал им советом и **участвовал на** разных совещаниях, ― время уходило у него на работу с другими дивизионными органами, к которым они с Чапаевым прикоснулись здесь впервые после Белебея. [Д. А. Фурманов. Чапаев (1923)]*

Примеры из нацкорпуса.